# SQL Azure connection error with User Assigned Managed Identity 'Login failed for user'

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-function-app, azure-managed-identity

I have a function app that is assigned a *[user assigned managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet)*, and it uses that to connect to the SQL database. This was working fine for a few days, but then suddenly stopped working, without any changes to db or the function app.

```
Error: Login failed for user '<ClientId>@<TenantId>'.
```

- **ClientId**: ClientId of the user assigned managed identity.
- **Tenant Id**: The tenant this identity exists in.

I searched online, and found [ways](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-connectivity-issues.md#diagnostics-examine-system-logs-for-errors) to look into a more detailed error in *sys.event_log*. As per this, I see that error is 18456, and state is 68. Unfortunately state 68 for error 18456 is not documented anywhere. ([Official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15)).

This is how I create a `SqlConnection` (and note that this was working before, and the same code is working elsewhere in the same exact setup):

```cs
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MyDb;");
connection.AccessToken = await new AzureServiceTokenProvider("RunAs=App;AppId=<ClientId>").GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/");
```

The user was created in db using:

```
CREATE USER [<Name of user assigned identity>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [<Name of user assigned identity>];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [<Name of user assigned identity>];
```

Any pointers to where I can look into next?

Note:

1. Using Azure Function Runtime 2.0 (dotnet core)
2. Using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication 1.4.0 (latest stable).

Comment: So you have other function apps (with different clientid's) working fine using this method, it's just this one that has the issue? I suggest that in the first instance you drop and recreate the user in SQL Server. Just to be clear, that connection string is using "User Assigned Identity", not "Managed  Identity".

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have another function app with a different user assigned identity talking to a different db. The code for both the apps is same, db schema is same. Basically one is staging, one is prod. Prod is still working. Staging stopped working suddenly even when there was no change. The user assigned identity is the client id of a managed identity created in azure portal, and assigned to the function app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find the root cause, but I am posting what helped me get unblocked so that hopefully it will help others in future.

For some reason all form of authentication (except by the AAD admin of the server) were failing on this server. So not only the user assigned identity authentication failed (which is described in the question above), but also [contained user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable?view=sql-server-ver15) auth failed. Removing the user assigned identity from db and re-adding didn't work:

```sql
DROP USER [<Name of user assigned identity>];
CREATE USER [<Name of user assigned identity>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [<Name of user assigned identity>];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [<Name of user assigned identity>];
```

Similarly dropping the contained user and recreating didn't work either.

```
DROP USER [ContainedUser];
CREATE USER [ContainedUser] WITH PASSWORD='******';
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [ContainedUser];
```

I also noticed that the secondary (i.e. replica) was working fine and auth was working against it. So basically I concluded something is wrong with my primary, not sure what exactly.

So I decided to recreate the database:

- I did a failover to the secondary.
- Remove the replication link, and then deleted the bad server. (just deleting the db and doing rest of the steps below wasn't enough, I did try)
- Recreated the server.
- Reconfigured replication so that the db got created on the new server as secondary.
- Did another failover so that the newly created db becomes the primary.
- All auth worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Has the service the Managed Identity is tied to been deleted and recreated?  If so the thumbprint in Azure AD has changed which is what SQL Server recognizes.  Unfortunately this is probably one of the few downsides to Managed Identities with SQL Databases and as far as I am aware the only service that requires this.  Try deleting and recreating the user and see if that works.

Going forward if doing CI/CD deployments it would be beneficial to have a simple SQL script to Drop and Recreate the user in the DB every time the Service connected to it is redeployed.

Such as:

```
BEGIN
DROP USER [MSI NAME]
    CREATE USER [MSI NAME] FROM  EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
    ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [MSI NAME];
    ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [MSI NAME];
END
GO
```

Comment: The managed identity has not been deleted and recreated. I tried the drop user and create user and that does not seem to help - same error. One other weird thing is that I also have another contained user created with `CREATE USER [name] WITH PASSWORD='<password>'`. This is also not working anymore (even though I can see this, and the Managed identity in Users in db). I am thinking something went wrong with the db. This db is part of a failover group, and I always use the failover grp's primary url to connect. And I can confirm there has been no automated or manual failover.

Comment: I noticed something very very **weird**. So I tried this sql auth login (the contained user that I explained above). This doesn't work when using server=primary, but works when server=secondary. I imagine same would happen with managed identity too. So for some reason, the primary db's auth mechanisms have got seriously messed up. I am thinking to do a failover and then failover back to smooth things out.

Comment: Yup. Something was wrong with server. I did a failover. And then stopped replication, and then deleted the problematic server. And then recreated the server and reconfigured failover group, which recreated the db. And that worked. Note that just deleting the db, and reconfiguring replication to recreate that db didn't help. Same error happened. I had to get rid of the problematic server. Not sure what happened, but something was messed up in sql server. I did check that firewall rules hadn't changed, and that there was nothing in activity log in past 1 week. so not sure what happened.

Answer (score 1):

I recently got a very similar error, and I am only posting in the case someone in the future finds the issue.

The error i got:  `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''.`

Which is not a very descriptive exception, because the actual cause was because I had misspelled the database name, when building the SQL connection. It makes sense if you think about it, as it could not find the database I was looking for, and as such could not connect with the managed identity user created as a external provider in it. Hence the `''` after `user` in the exception.

When i changed the misspelled database name back to the actual database name, authentication was successful again.

Answer (score 0):

To leverage a user-assigned identity, you will need to provide an additional configuration. Please see [connection string support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support) for the `AppAuthentication` library.

[image]

When creating the SQL user, make sure to **use the name of the user-assigned identity** resource rather than the site name.

Comment: I am using that connection string (see question above). I also just updated the question and added the SQL statement that was used to create the user.