# Azure SQL with Managed Identity (user-assigned) failed to login

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-managed-identity

I'm using .NET **Framework** (not Core!) 4.7.2 and am trying to use a User-Assigned Managed Identity to connect to an Azure SQL Server. The Managed Identity object has been added to `db_datareader`, `db_datawriter` roles on the Azure SQL server and has permissions to connect. (independently verified with our ASP.NET Core app).

However it fails when we try to do it from our command-line .NET Framework app running on a VM that has been enabled on the managed identity. The code to connect to Azure SQL looks roughly like this:

```
// .NET Framework 4.7.2
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MyDb;")){
    var credential = new ManagedIdentityCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ManagedIdentityId"]);
    conn.AccessToken = await credential.GetTokenAsync(
                          new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" })
                       );
    ....
}
```

It manages to grab a token just fine (from the logs below), but fails with this error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''
```

What should I check?

(the very same code works fine from ASP.NET Core)

Appendix

- Very similar to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61644229/sql-azure-connection-error-with-user-assigned-managed-identity-login-failed-for), but in our case not all forms of auth failed on the Azure SQL server. We were able to login manually with AAD accounts. It's only the User-Assigned Managed Identity called from .NET Framework 4.7.2 that is failing (it works fine from our ASP.NET Core program, same code)
- Logs here

```
2021-06-15 14:39:28.7200|INFO|Logger|Received TOKEN - [xxxx real token here xxxx]
2021-06-15 14:39:28.9387|ERROR|Logger|Exception occurred: 
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, 
      SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, 
      SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, 
      Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, 
                                                                  Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, 
                                                                  DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, 
                                                                          DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, 
                                                                          DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, 
                                                                 Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, 
                                                                 DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, It is Ok for me. My steps are as below.

1. [Assign MSI to the VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vm#assign-a-user-assigned-managed-identity-to-an-existing-vm).
2. Configure Azure AD auth

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS [the msi name]
GO
CREATE USER [the msi name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
GO
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [the msi name];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [the msi name];
GRANT EXECUTE TO [the msi name]
GO
```

3. Install package

```
Install-Package Azure.Identity -Version 1.4.0
Install-Package System.Data.SqlClient -Version 4.8.2
```

4. Code

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string conStr = "Server=tcp:testsql09.database.windows.net,1433;Database=test;";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                var credential = new ManagedIdentityCredential("ed5f***823");
                connection.AccessToken = (await credential.GetTokenAsync(
                              new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net//.default" })
                    )).Token;
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM Blogs";

                using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1));
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            Console.Read();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your walkthru. It was extremely well-written, and helped to uncover the problem. Turns out the SqlClient package was problem. It was included via 'using System.Data.Client' but the Nuget package manager couldn't see it -- removing everything and reinstalling resolved the issue. I'm not sure I understand how that could have caused the "Login failed for user ''" error, but it resolved the issue. Thanks again!